# CastCompanionLibrary-android: Failed to detach data channels

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I'm using the DataCastManager with my application and I'm getting this error a lot after I disconnect (Failed to detach data channels). What makes it worse is that the application has to be restarted to be able to get chromecast functionality back. I'm using the latest version of the CastCompanionLibary-android (fbbd834ab3 Feb 13th). Any pointers? Am I doing something wrong?

```
02-17 22:36:47.614: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7415): onDisconnected() reached
02-17 22:36:47.630: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7415): Trying to disconnect
02-17 22:36:55.716: D/ccl_CastMediaRouterCal(7415): onRouteSelected: info=MediaRouter.RouteInfo{ uniqueId=com.google.android.gms/.cast.media.CastMediaRouteProviderService:1c55e6852ee04d6597450b7ccbd5a735, name=Chromecast3036, description=Ready to play, enabled=true, connecting=false, playbackType=1, playbackStream=-1, volumeHandling=1, volume=20, volumeMax=20, presentationDisplayId=-1, extras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=572], providerPackageName=com.google.android.gms }
02-17 22:36:55.724: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7415): acquiring a conenction to Google Play services for "Chromecast3036" (1c55e6852ee04d6597450b7ccbd5a735)
02-17 22:36:55.755: D/ccl_CastMediaRouterCal(7415): onResult: mSelectedDevice=Chromecast3036
02-17 22:37:11.068: I/MediaRouter(7415): Unselecting the current route because it is no longer selectable: MediaRouter.RouteInfo{ uniqueId=com.google.android.gms/.cast.media.CastMediaRouteProviderService:1c55e6852ee04d6597450b7ccbd5a735, name=Chromecast3036, description=Ready to play, enabled=true, connecting=false, playbackType=1, playbackStream=-1, volumeHandling=1, volume=20, volumeMax=20, presentationDisplayId=-1, extras=Bundle[{com.google.android.gms.cast.EXTRA_CAST_DEVICE="Chromecast3036" (1c55e6852ee04d6597450b7ccbd5a735)}], providerPackageName=com.google.android.gms }
02-17 22:37:11.083: D/ccl_CastMediaRouterCal(7415): onRouteUnselected: route=MediaRouter.RouteInfo{ uniqueId=com.google.android.gms/.cast.media.CastMediaRouteProviderService:1c55e6852ee04d6597450b7ccbd5a735, name=Chromecast3036, description=Ready to play, enabled=true, connecting=false, playbackType=1, playbackStream=-1, volumeHandling=1, volume=20, volumeMax=20, presentationDisplayId=-1, extras=Bundle[{com.google.android.gms.cast.EXTRA_CAST_DEVICE="Chromecast3036" (1c55e6852ee04d6597450b7ccbd5a735)}], providerPackageName=com.google.android.gms }
02-17 22:37:11.099: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7415): onDisconnected() reached
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415): Failed to detach data channels
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415): com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.exceptions.NoConnectionException
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.BaseCastManager.checkConnectivity(BaseCastManager.java:1035)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.DataCastManager.detachDataChannels(DataCastManager.java:414)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.DataCastManager.onDeviceUnselected(DataCastManager.java:273)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.BaseCastManager.setDevice(BaseCastManager.java:253)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.BaseCastManager.onDeviceSelected(BaseCastManager.java:223)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.CastMediaRouterCallback.onRouteUnselected(CastMediaRouterCallback.java:67)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter$CallbackHandler.invokeCallback(MediaRouter.java:2091)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(MediaRouter.java:2038)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-17 22:37:11.169: E/ccl_DataCastManager(7415):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 22:37:11.169: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7415): Trying to disconnect
```

Comment: Can you try the following: comment out the body of the onDeviceUnselected() in DataCastManager, line 271 (comment out lines 272-278) and see if all works fie for you or not.

Comment: Thanks @Ali. That fixed the Exception but the Chromecast icon still went away and I can't reconnect. I'm being able to reproduce this only in one particular wireless network. I'll keep testing and will net you know if I get any other insights.